# How to make unequal length strings equal to one another?

Tags: r, string, stringr

Is there a way to make one string match the length of another string? Basically what needs to happen is the string in value 2 should be made to the size of value 3's string.

The original data frame is as follows

| type | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inner | 0.52,0.11,0.08 | 1.3,1.9,2.8,1.08 | 56.9,60.1,1.0 |
| Outer | 0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01 | 0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31,7.19,3.29 | 93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98 |
| Median | 0.10 | 8.10,9.56 | 3.10 |

The desired output is

| type | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inner | 0.52,0.11,0.08 | 1.3,1.9,2.8 | 56.9,60.1,1.0 |
| Outer | 0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01 | 0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31 | 93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98 |
| Median | 0.10 | 8.10 | 3.10 |

What needs to happen is the extra numbers (or words if there are words instead of numbers) in the string of value2 should be cut off to be equal to the length of value3.

Comment: Do you mean the length of the string in terms of character count, or the number of values separated by ","?

Comment: Are these strings or list columns? And if they're strings, do they need to be? Seems like `list` columns would make more sense.

Comment: It'd be clearer if you share the output of `dput(your_dataframe)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have comma separated values in strings. Based on your desired output, I am interpreting your question such that you mean the number of comma separated elements that should be equal, not the string length. Depending on the use case it might make more sense to store these in list columns instead, but that is your choice of course. Here, I convert them to list columns, subset the elements of `value2` according to the length of `value3` and then convert them to strings again. Delete the last step if you want to retain the list columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(
  type = c("Inner", "Outer", "Median"), 
  value1 = c("0.52,0.11,0.08", "0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01", "0.10"), 
  value2 = c("1.3,1.9,2.8,1.08", "0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31,7.19,3.29", "8.10,9.56"), 
  value3 = c("56.9,60.1,1.0", "93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98", "3.10")
)

d |> 
  mutate(
    across(value2:value3, str_split, pattern = ","),
    value2 = map_int(value3, length) |> 
      map2(value2, \(l3, v2) v2[seq_len(l3)]),
    across(value2:value3, map_chr, str_c, collapse = ",")
    )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   type   value1              value2             value3              
#>   <chr>  <chr>               <chr>              <chr>               
#> 1 Inner  0.52,0.11,0.08      1.3,1.9,2.8        56.9,60.1,1.0       
#> 2 Outer  0.12,3.09,5.91,0.01 0.1,0.35,1.93,9.31 93.53,0.87,0.65,0.98
#> 3 Median 0.10                8.10               3.10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>